# uicollectionviewcell labels misaligned after reload

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[image: This is how it looks]

I tried following code to render simple collection view on screen.
But subviews in contentview do not algin properly

I am coding in swift 2.3 with Xcode 7.3.1
Whys is this happening?

Here is the code

```
import Foundation
class CustomerOverdueViewController : BaseViewController , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblTotalOverdue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblInvestedFunds: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    var rangeArray = NSArray()
    var selectedOverdueIndex = 0
    var selectedColor = UIColor()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Customer Overdue"

    }


    @IBAction func segValueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let reuseIdentifier = String("CustomerOverdueCollectionViewCell")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomerOverdueCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/2 - 10, height: collectionView.frame.size.height/3 - 10)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
    {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 10.0
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 10.0
    }

}
```

Comment: are you using autolayout or autoresizing?

Comment: A am using autolayouts

Comment: i think you are having conflict in contraints in collectionview resolve them You will be able to get deisred output.Please post initial image , which look  neat before reload

Comment: Actually the view loads properly when the data is loaded from the local database. Only when the view is loaded from the response of the api the issue occurs. I doubt this to be a threading issue and not an auto-layout issue

Comment: reload collectionview in main thread then

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got the solution

Override layoutSubviews in Custom Cell

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

and add following lines in cellForItemAtIndexpath

```
    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in the initial call the data is used when the table is first drawn (from ViewWillLoad). However when you refresh the data, the constraints are not recalculated.

Normally this is done via setNeedsLayout and/or layoutIfNeeded
You can try:

```
[view layoutIfNeeded];
```